# Computing a constant of weak convexity for $|x^2 - b|$

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and set $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\colon x\mapsto |x^2-b|$. This function is weakly convex. It [appears](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1b0m0joebq) that its weak convexity constant, i.e. the $\beta\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$, which makes $f(x)+\frac{\beta}{2}\|x\|^2$ convex, is $2$. However, I have not found a proof of this. This seems like it should be an exercise in a convex analysis text somewhere. Anyone know where I can find it? Alternatively, a simple proof will also suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by weakly convex you mean mid point convex then $f$ is not weakly convex:
$f(0) = |b| > {1 \over 2} f(-b)+f(b)=0$.

If this is not the definition let me know in the comments and I will delete this answer.

I am not exactly sure what you mean by weak convexity constant, I am taking it to be the smallest $\beta$ such that $f_\beta = f(x) + { \beta \over 2} x^2$
is convex.

If $b \le 0$ then $f$ is convex (since $f(x) = x^2+|b|$) and so $\beta = -2$.

If $b > 0$ then it is straightforward to compute $\beta$.

For $x^2 < b$ we have $f_\beta'(x) = (\beta-2) x$ and since $f_\beta'$ needs to be non decreasing so
we need $\beta \ge 2$.

Note that $f_2(x) = \max(b,2x^2-b)$, hence $\beta = 2$ is the minimum value of $\beta$ that makes $f_\beta$ convex is $2$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: $f$ is weakly convex if there exists $\beta\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$ such that $f(\cdot)+\beta\|\cdot\|^2/2$ is convex. Any such $\beta$ is a weak convexity constant of $f$. Also, could you please provide a bit more explanation in justification that $f_{\beta}$ is convex for $\beta=2$? As written, I don't quite follow the argument.

Comment: For the $b>0$ case, since $f_2$ is the $\max$ of two convex functions it is convex. (One cute way of seeing this is to note that the epigraph of the $\max$ is the intersection of the epigraphs.)

Comment: Oh neato! Actually it looks like all we need is just that last line, since the max of convex functions remains convex. Cool observation, thanks!